# JS Error : too much recursion in jquery-1.4.4.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm opening a dialog using jQuery. When I try to close the dialog, it throws a `js error`

> ```
> "Error: too much recursion Source File:
> ```
>
> http://localhost:8080/testProject/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js
>   Line: 648"

The functions for dialogues are as follows :

```
jQuery(function() {

        jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice-form" ).dialog({
            bgiframe:true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 550,
            width: 870,
            modal: true,
            resizable : true,

            close: function() {
                jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice-form" ).dialog( "close" );
            }

        });

        jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice" ).button().click(function() {
                jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
```

Comment: You may use 'jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );' instead of 'jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice-form" ).dialog( "close" );'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changed the code according to your suggestion, no success.

Comment: You would be creating an infinite loop telling the dialog to close everytime you tell it to close. The close event means that the dialog is already closing. You want to put the "close" command on a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice-form" ).dialog({
            bgiframe:true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 550,
            width: 870,
            modal: true,
            resizable : true,

            close: function() {
            },
            buttons: {
               'Close': function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
```

This is how it should be done - don't tell it to close everytime it is closing, else you get a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove this code

```
jQuery( "#purchaseOrderDevice-form" ).dialog( "close" );
```

Because when you call `close: function() {}` that dialog has been closed, so when you try to close it again, it will cause that error

Hope this helps